# Expresar nadie en álgebra relacional

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico, álgebra-relacional

Tengo cinco tablas

- Espectáculo(**EspectáculoID**, Titulo, FechaEmp, Duración, SalaID, Cantador)
- Concierto(**ConciertoID**, Fecha, Horario, EspectáculoID)
- Sala(**SalaID**, Nombre, Direccion, Capacidad)
- Billete(**BilleteID**, ConciertoID, PosiciónNum, Categoría, Precio)
- Vender(**VentaID**, FechaVenta, BilleteID, FormaDePago)

¿Cómo expresar en álgebra relacional las personas que **no** han realizado un Concierto en el Liceu? (Una sala de concierto muy bonita en Barcelona).

> El **álgebra relacional** es un conjunto de operaciones que describen paso
>   a paso cómo computar una respuesta sobre las relaciones, tal y como
>   éstas son definidas en el modelo relacional. Denominada de tipo
>   procedimental, a diferencia del Cálculo relacional que es de tipo
>   declarativo.

He traido:

[image: Trae]

Pero no sé si estoy expresando aquellos que han realizado un concierto en el Liceu para removerlos de todos los Cantador.

Además no sé si es necesario escribir lo que escribí bajo el ⋈, ¿es suficiente el hecho de que la columna SalaID de Espectáculo está también en la Salas?.

Comment: Hola @Marine1, creo que estás confundiendo los términos, donde dices bases de datos deberías decir tablas. Lo de álgebra relacional tampoco lo había escuchado nunca, ¿quizás debería de decirse condiciones, criterio de selección? Lo adecuado sería adaptar la para que se entienda mejor

Comment: @rsciriano Muchas gracias! Eso es: tablas! Sin embargo es álgebra relacional por seguro, aquí esta la página wikipedia https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_relacional

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya he visto el [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_relacional) lo que es álgebra relacional ¿Para que lo usas? ¿Tiene alguna utilidad practica?

Comment: @rsciriano Si, por seguro! Esta la base que funda el languaje sql. Lo utiliso siguiendo un curso de sql en la universidad.

Comment: Pues lo siento, igual es que yo no aprendí SQL en la universidad pero no lo veo nada útil. Vería mas útil saber porque una forma de hacer una consulta es mas óptima que otra, como hay que diseñar los índices, elementos como el optimizador de consultas, cache,... supongo que también os lo explicarán ¿no?

Comment: El álgebra relacional es súper importante, no debe ser desacreditada como algo inútil. Ahora, tengo dudas ¿qué es el Liceu? ¿Sala, concierto, espectáculo? Quizá debas detallar más tu pregunta antes de que podamos ayudarte. Otra duda, la respuesta esperada es ¿una consulta en sql? Por que veo que has etiquetado tu pregunta como tal.

Comment: @Gepser Muchas gracias! El Liceu es una Sala muy concocida en Barcelona. Debería haber explicado mejor. He eticado sql porque no hay etiqueta por el álgebra relacional.

Comment: agregué la etiqueta de lenguaje agnóstico, no sé si corresponde crear la de álgebra relacional si es así la creamos.

Comment: @Alan Si, pienso que es necesario. Como Gesper lo decía "El álgebra relacional es súper importante" es fundamental para entender el SQL y los lenguajes similares.

Comment: ya agregué la etiqueta y voté para reabrir.

Comment: @Alan, muchas gracias! Pienso que sería una vergünza cerrarla... En efecto álgebra relacional no esta muy desconocido por los programadores. Es un metalenguaje de programación.

Comment: @Alan, Marine1 No pretendía desacreditar la pregunta, aunque quizás fui demasiado brusco en mis comentarios. Que algo no sea útil para una persona, no significa que no sea importante. Y algo más que he aprendido, el significado porque quizás estoy lejos de aplicarlo en la práctica (o no, quien sabe). Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si entendí bien la pregunta, quieres los *`Cantador`*(¿cantantes?) que **no** han tenido un concierto en la sala "Liceu"

Ahora si es que logro recordar mis clases de algebra relacional y le acierto a la sintáxis, una solución es:

```
ΠCantador(Espectáculo) - ΠCantador(σNombre=Liceu(Espectáculo ⋈ Sala))
```

Aquí lo que ocurre es, se obtiene el conjunto *cantador* total, luego el conjunto *cantador* quienes si han participado en la sala "Liceu" y se calcula la diferencia entre ambos.

> Además no sé si esta necesario escribir lo que esribi con el ⋈ porque ya esta sufficiente o no el echo de que los SalaID de Espectáculo estan los SalaID de las Salas.

En la unión natural (⋈) si se omite la condición significa que la comparación se realiza por todas las columnas comunes entre las 2 tablas, en este caso `SalaID`, por lo tanto no es necesario especificarlo.